# jqGrid Internationalization

Tags: javascript, html, internationalization, jqgrid

I use jqGrid grid table plugin for my HTML files. How can I internationalize my table's column, header etc? I mean I will load a property file or change a variable, my table template will be in that language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply replace:

```
<script src="js/lib/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
```

with a language of your choice, like:

```
<script src="js/lib/grid.locale-pl.js"></script>
```

Standard (English) locale, Redmond theme:

[image: English, Redmond]

Polish locale, Le Frog jQuery UI theme:

[image: Polish, Le Frog]

[Source](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2011/07/poor-mans-crud-jqgrid-rest-ajax-and.html)

Comment: voting up for good documentation reference. That was exactly what I was working on.

Comment: +1 the screenshots are taken from Thomasz's excellent blog post on jqGrid, well worth the read : http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.ch/2011/07/poor-mans-crud-jqgrid-rest-ajax-and.html

Answer (score 4):

I wrote my suggestion how one can implement the jqGrid internationalization in [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/small-changes-in-i18ngrid-locale-xx-js-files-to-make-possible-dynamic-language-switching/#p22314). See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization1.htm) for example. You can make yourself the changes which I suggestion. One needs only to modify the "i18n/grid.locale-XX.js" files **without changing** of the main jqGrid code.

So you will be able to implement pages which supports many languages, the default language will be choosed based on the language of the web browser. Moreover you can allow the user to change the jqGrid language dynamically from

[image]

to

[image]

for example.

P.S. [Another old suggestion](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/many-small-bugs-in-grid-locale-xx-js-files-and-new-way-to-implement-jqgrid-localization/#p21552) to use jQuery Globalization plugin could be also interesting for you.

Comment: instead of importing all the js files into my page is there a way to get a language property by JSON dynamically from a remote server?

Comment: @kamaci: There are different server based ways to archive the same, but it will be *not jqGrid question*. jqGrid use JavaScript "i18n/grid.locale-XX.js" files as the information source. If you would just include the files on the server based on the language of the web-browser it could be not what one really mean under internationalize. All depend on requirements and you should more exactly define what features you need to have. If you look [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#localization) and examine `i18n` directory of jQuery UI you will see the things very close to which I suggested

Comment: @Oleg: I am using JQGrid in Ruby on Rails. I saw your demo and i am looking for the same. But the link https://github.com/jquery/jquery-global is not working as it is throwing 404 (page not found) error. Can you please provide the source code to implement jqgrid internationalization.

Comment: @neeraj: the current place of jQuery Globalize is [here](https://github.com/jquery/globalize).

Comment: @Oleg: does that code include code to globalize JQGrid as well? If No, then please provide. Actually i just need to globalize JQGrid

Comment: @neeraj: What you mean under "globalize JQGrid"? I posted suggestions how one can modify code of "i18n/grid.locale-XX.js" to make easy to switch language of jqGrid dynamically. You can just follow the suggestions. The main advantage is that you need modify only `**grid.locale-XX.js**` files. So you can use *original* version of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`

Comment: @neeraj: Sorry, but I don't understand what is the problem. Just open the demo in web browser open context menu (right mouse click) and choose the item "View page source" or "View source" (the exact name of item depends on the browser which you use). You will see full source code of the demo. The demo contains links like `http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/i18n/grid.locale-en-fixed.js`. You can open the links in web browser and see the corresponding code too.

Comment: @Oleg: Sorry, i thought you may have placed entire package at github..Anyways please dont' mind. I will get the code from browser.

Comment: @Oleg: Your code is working fine but when i adjusted your code as per my requirement then i got error "ReferenceError: curLanguage is not defined". Is it possible for you to see(by posting a new question here or sending you code by email) what i am missing?

Comment: @neeraj: You can post new question on the stackoverflow. I'll try to look at this.

Comment: Done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582891/dynamic-jqgrid-internationalization

Answer (score 0):

If you're using version 4.8 and above, regional parameter can be set in grid control.

E.g
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
...
regional : 'cn',
...
});