# How Can Translate Search operation in JQGrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

How can translate Search opetarion in JQGrid search box in Search box For example, instead of equal use = simbole.

[image]

thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jqgrid](/questions/tagged/jqgrid) has full [i18n](/questions/tagged/i18n) support, check out: [jqGrid Internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175673). Looks like you are using Arabic. Simply replace:

```
<script src="js/lib/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
```

with Arabic language:

```
<script src="js/lib/grid.locale-ar.js"></script>
```

The latter file is part of the jqGrid distribution and contains all you need:

`grid.locale-en.js`:

```
$.jgrid = {
    search : {
        odata : ['equal', 'not equal', 'less', 'less or equal','greater','greater or equal', 'begins with','does not begin with','is in','is not in','ends with','does not end with','contains','does not contain'],
```

`grid.locale-ar.js`:

```
$.jgrid = {
    search : {
        odata : ['يساوي', 'يختلف', 'أقل', 'أقل أو يساوي','أكبر','أكبر أو يساوي', 'يبدأ بـ','لا يبدأ بـ','est dans',"n'est pas dans",'ينته بـ','لا ينته بـ','يحتوي','لا يحتوي'],
```

Comment: thanks but, I Want Use Persion (Farsi) Language but in i18n is't have file for persion language

Comment: @mohsen: forgive my lack of Persian and Arabic knowledge. I have just downloaded jqGrid and it has Persion (`fa`) i18n file. It is also available in the [source repository](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/i18n/grid.locale-fa.js) If it does not meet your requirements, you can always write your own and contribute it.