# Dynamic JQGrid Internationalization

Tags: dynamic, jqgrid, internationalization

I am using JQGrid in Ruby on Rails that pulls data from a controller and that controller return data in json format. Below is my JQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var list = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
    grid = $("#list");
    grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "json",
        url:'/applications?'+new Date().getTime(),
        height: <%= JQGRID_HEIGHT %>,
        rowNum:<%= ROW_NUM %>, 
        rowList:<%= ROW_LIST %>,
        viewrecords: true,
        autowidth:true,
        gridComplete: function() {
            initLytebox();
            common.jqGridComplete($(this));
            initLytebox();

        },
        afterInsertRow: function(rowId) {           
            var action = grid.jqGrid('getRowData',rowId).action;
            var cellValue = '<a href="/applications/'+rowId+'/edit"><img alt="Edit" src="/assets/edit.png" title="Edit"></a>&nbsp;'
            cellValue += '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteApplication('+rowId+')" class = "delete_egress_group" id = "'+rowId+'">';            
            cellValue += '<img alt="Delete" src="/assets/delete.png" title="Delete"></a>';
            grid.jqGrid('setRowData',rowId,{action:cellValue});
        },
        colNames:['Application Name','Description','Action'],       
        colModel:[  
                    {name:'name',index:'name', width:"20%"},
                    {name:'description',index:'description', width:"70%"},
                    {name:'action',index:'action', width:"10%",search:false,sortable:false}
                 ],              
        multiselect: false,
        pager: '#pager',
        toolbar: [true,"top"],
        caption: "Applications" }
    );  
    grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {search: false, add: false, edit: false, del: false },{}, {}, {},
     { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false});
    grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, defaultSearch: 'cn' });
    grid.jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager',
        {
            caption: "Add",title: "Add New",buttonicon: 'ui-icon-plus',
            onClickButton: function () {window.location = "/applications/new";}             
        }
    );
}); 
</script>
<select id="languages">
    <option value="en">English (US)</option>
    <option value="en-GB">English (GB)</option>
    <option value="en-IN">English (IN)</option>
    <option value="de">German</option>
    <option value="ru">Russian</option>
</select>
<div style="width:100%">
    <table id="list"></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</div>
```

I have downloaded multi-lingual js files from below locations and placed under JQGrid folder of my application

```
http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/i18n/grid.locale-en-fixed.js
http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/i18n/grid.locale-ru-fixed.js
http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-3.8.2/src/i18n/grid.locale-de-fixed.js
```

Now i simply want to convert the column header and Pagination strings of my JQGrid as per the selected language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use locale files from very old version of jqGrid (3.8.2) described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7176964/315935). I verified and the same idea can be still used in jqGrid.

**[Here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization_.htm) is modified version of [the old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization.htm) which works**. If you compare the original localization files (for example [grid.locale-en.js](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.3/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js)) with the modified version (for example [grid.locale-en-dyn.js](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid-4.4.3/js/i18n/grid.locale-en-dyn.js)) you will see that the modification which I done very easy. The original file `grid.locale-en.js` which looks like

```js
(function($){
....
$.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
$.extend($.jgrid,{
    defaults : {
    ....
});
})(jQuery);
```

I modified to

```js
(function($){
....
$.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
if (!$.jgrid.hasOwnProperty("regional")) {
    $.jgrid.regional = {};
}
$.jgrid.regional.en = $.jgrid.regional["en-US"] = {
    defaults : {
    ....
};
$.extend($.jgrid,$.jgrid.regional.en);
})(jQuery);
```

Such modification allows to save the language specific information not only in the **common** part like `$.jgrid.defaults.recordtext`, but **additionally** in the language specific parts like `$.jgrid.regional.en.defaults.recordtext` and `$.jgrid.regional["en-US"].defaults.recordtext`. It allows to include **multiple** language specific settings which can be copied to the standard `$.jgrid.defaults` part used by jqGrid.