# jqGrid date formatting i18n internationalisation file

Tags: jqgrid, internationalization

I am using jqGrid and there is only 1 file for English in the i18n folder, the issue is that dates are in `MM/DD/YYYY` format and I need them to be in `DD/MM/YYYY` format.  Perhaps one could just create a new `grid.locale-en-gb.js` file with a different date formatter.  There already appears to be a separate file for Brazilian Portuguese.  However since I am only changing the date formatter, perhaps there is a better way to just change this.

Comment: when adding a new grid.locale.en-GB.js, everything the same except line 106: newformat: 'j/n/Y', and line 121 ShortDate: "j/n/Y",                   Unhandled exception at line 123, column 320 in http://localhost:52226/Scripts/JqGrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'integer' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Information about line number of jquery.jqGrid.min.js gives **no information**. You should always use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` during debugging. What you mean with "adding a new grid.locale.en-GB.js"? You should *replace* the usage of `grid.locale-en.js` with you modified version `grid.locale-en-gb.js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is just to specify

```js
formatoptions: { newformat: "d/m/Y"}
```

in the `colModel` together with other options

```js
sorttype: "date", formatter: "date"
```

which hopefully use already. If you prefer to create `grid.locale-en-gb.js` file then you can copy `grid.locale-en.js` and modify [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js#L104)

```js
newformat: 'n/j/Y',
```

to

```js
newformat: 'd/m/Y',
```

The file `grid.locale-en.js` contains many comments. You can change other settings to be more GB conform.

I recommend you additionally to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7176964/315935) and [the feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/small-changes-in-i18ngrid-locale-xx-js-files-to-make-possible-dynamic-language-switching/#p22314) which described how to change locale of jqGrid dynamically. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization1.htm) demonstrate the approach.

Comment: yes I can add a custom date format to the col model, but this is an array, so I can not put an if statement around it to check the window.navigator.userLanguage  I need to

Comment: @magister: You asked in your question about the usage of date corresponds to GB English format. **Dynamical switching of locale is absolutely another requirement**. Nevertheless I described the implementation way in [the feature request](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/small-changes-in-i18ngrid-locale-xx-js-files-to-make-possible-dynamic-language-switching/#p22314). [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Localization1.htm) do this. The demo displays the grid per default based on `navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage` value.