# jqGrid Language Detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, internationalization, jqgrid-asp.net

I am working on JqGrid and came across an issue related language. I need to support both English & French.

I added English and French locale file into the scripts folder and referred the files in the html file.But the jqGrid is not detecting the browser language automatically and display the last loaded language always.

Is there a better solution for this issue?  Ideally, jqGrid should have capability to detect the language and load the locale file automatically. Couldnt find a solution anywhere.

Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175673/jqgrid-internationalization

Comment: Thanks. But they are asking to replace the English file with another language file. That wont work here. My application serve both english and french users.ideally, jqGrid should automatically fetch the correct locale file based on browser language settings.